I have a above ground pool 24' x 52" round the problem I have is the suction side from the skimmer will not work with a auto cleaner I lose suction
the pool takes 15000 gal of water I have a 1 1/2 HP pump with a 22 sand filter instead of sand I used the what i call cotton balls and the suction fills like it is getting worse could it be the cotton balls?

Certainly seems so. Without knowing exactly what you are using, impossible to be more precise.

What happens when you take the "cotton balls" out?

Are "cotton balls" recommended for your filter.  Most filters have recommended mediums you can use in them.

Water flow and pump suction will be reduced when the filter needs backwashed, try backwashing if you haven't yet.  Max flow and suction can be checked by bypassing the filter and media - typical valve units can be set to do so, usually called 'recirculate' rather than 'filter'.
